# Pgadmin ERROR: could not open file reading: Permission denied

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a newbie for Psql, just wanted to copy the data into psql with codes:

```
COPY consumer_complaints
FROM '/users/xxxx/Desktop/ConsumerComplaints.csv';
```

But, it wouldn't allow me to, as it showed following:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/users/xxxx/Desktop/ConsumerComplaints.csv" for reading: Permission denied HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy. SQL state: 42501
```

I am so desperate at this point I don't know what to do.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFONT.png) is a sample of the data.

This is the permission of the file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7zSu.png)

**update:**

03/22/2020: 
1. I tried replay `copy` with `\copy`, and it still didnt work.

Comment: Are you sure that you have permission to read the file? Have you tried to replace `COPY` with `\copy`?

Comment: @siyopao Yes, I tried. and it just turned into plain text right after.

Answer (score 0):

You should try *steps*:

1. Right-click on the file
2. Go to **Get info** > **Sharing and
   permissions**
3. Click on <kbd>+</kbd> button and add PostgreSQL to permission
   read this file.